# How to see the header/content details of App Service 400 errors in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

An app service in Azure is showing 400 errors for about 0.05% of requests.

I can see the number of errors and the endpoints hit if I go into the app service in Azure portal, click on "Diagnose and solve problems", click on "Availability and Performance", and click on "HTTP 4xx Errors".

Is it possible to see the header and content of these failed requests or see any more details about them to try to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

- As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#log-detailed-errors), we can enable the detailed errors by setting the `Detailed error messages` and `Failed request tracing` On
- Navigate to Azure Portal => your Web App => `App Service Logs` Under `Monotoring` and Enable  `Detailed error messages` and `Failed request tracing`  and save

[image]

- As per this [document](https://www.azureblue.io/how-to-log-http-request-body-with-asp-net-core-application-insights/)

> We  can use Application Insights  to get the request and response body.

Please refer [Enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-windows) for more information