# How to get detailed 400 error information on a Linux Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to get detailed 400 error information on a Linux Azure App Service? I would like to see if the json in the post is causing the errors I am getting. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72865897/how-to-see-the-header-content-details-of-app-service-400-errors-in-azure) and it seems to be Windows specific. [This Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-windows) specifies that `Detailed Error Messages` and `Failed request tracing` are only available on [Windows App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#log-detailed-errors).

Comment: Have you tried Application Insights ?

Comment: No. I see the response below and will see if that gets me what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the same Doc you can see the Linux App Service also have an option for File System Logging.

[image]

- You can also see the logs in `Log stream`.

[image]

- One more option to check logs is in newui => FileManager => LogFiles.

```cs
https://YourAppname.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/
```

[image]

If you want to get the detailed error of the logs, configuring Application Insights is the better option.

***Application Insights Transaction Search:***

[image]

Comment: I'm specifically looking for what json field caused the problem. I found the information in the response in swift but wanted it on the server as well. Let me look at application insights (will mark as answer when confirmed). Though not a part of the question I did see a `traceId` in the swift response, which would be great to match up to server.